# ExtJs Autohide window

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, hide, extjs3

I want to make a status window displays some data, depending on the user's actions. How can I do so that the window after 10 seconds automatically hidden?

```
 this.statusWin = new Ext.Window({
     height: winHeight,
     x: document.body.clientWidth - winWidth,
     y: document.body.clientHeight - winHeight,
     width: winWidth,
     layout: 'fit',
     items: status_message,
     baseCls: 'lk-statusWindow',
     hideBorder: false,
     resizable: false,
     closeAction: 'hide',
     plain: true
 });
```

Use ExtJs3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function with delay:

```
var closeWithDelay = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
    this.statusWin.hide(); // or destroy
});

this.statusWin.on('show', function(){
    closeWithDelay.delay(10000); 
});
```